# Xcode: Make UIButton inactive until WebView is completely loaded?

Tags: xcode, button, hide

I have an App here, which loads a ModalView (WebView) which contains a Camera button. The problem is, when the Webpage has not been loaded completely, and I press the Camera button and dismiss it, then I have a white Screen, respectively the website has been interupted when loading.

Therefore, I want to make the camera button "inactive" as long as the Webpage is loading. How can I manage to do this? Here is my actual code:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ATWebViewController class]]) {
    NSURL *url = nil;
    if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 0) {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.bikemarkt.mtb-news.de"];
    }
    else if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1) {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://winterpokal.mtb-news.de"];
    }
```

//        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag==0 
        ATWebViewController *webViewController = [[ATWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil URL:url ];

```
    //Check if the device is running iOS 6.x.x and if yes, then show the camera button

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] hasPrefix:@"5"]) {

    UINavigationController *navigationBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    navigationBarController.navigationBar.tintColor = ATNavigationBarTintColor;

    if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 0) {

    webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebView)];
        }

     else if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1) {

    webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebView)];
         }

    navigationBarController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationBarController animated:YES];
    return NO;
        }

    // If not iOS 5

    else

        { UINavigationController *navigationBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

        navigationBarController.navigationBar.tintColor = ATNavigationBarTintColor;

        if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 0) {

            webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebView)];
            webViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(TakePhoto)];
        }

        else if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1) {

            webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebView)];
        }

        navigationBarController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentModalViewController:navigationBarController animated:YES];
        return NO;
    }


}
return YES;
```

}

@end

Any Help would be highly appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0):

implement `webViewDidFinishLoading:` from the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol

only in there set the button to take the photo, not right away

Comment: I have to if statements: First is if Tag is=0 and the second is if iOS is 6.xx

How can I implement this?

Comment: Hm, I've tried to accomplish what you told me, but it appears, that I'm too much a noob... :(